# R packages not connecting to peer for data download

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am working with a couple of R packages for genetic pathway enrichment analyses and the two packages that I am using are now throwing errors when trying to connect to each package's respective server for downloading the reference data for the analysis.

In the first package `gage`, I am getting the following error when attempting to download:

```
library(gage)

> kg.ko = kegg.gsets("ko") # ("ko" is KEGG ortholog pathway)
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

In the second package `clusterProfiler`, I am getting the following error:

```
library(clusterProfiler)

# the data
dput(head(de_kegg_chr))
c("K14847", "K19009", "K00078", "K21407", "K23285", "K06972")

# KEGG enrichment (which will pull relevant reference data during this step)
# over-representation analysis (fisher's)

>   enrich <- enrichKEGG(gene = de_kegg_chr,
+                        organism = "ko",
+                        keyType='kegg',
+                        pvalueCutoff = 0.01)
Reading KEGG annotation online:

fail to download KEGG data...
Error in download.KEGG.Path(species) : 
  'species' should be one of organisms listed in 'http://www.genome.jp/kegg/catalog/org_list.html'...
In addition: Warning message:
In utils::download.file(url, quiet = TRUE, method = method, ...) :
  URL 'https://rest.kegg.jp/link/ko/pathway': status was 'Failure when receiving data from the peer'
```

After the first error, I thought it was something specific to the `gage` package and found a simple work-around because these data are downloaded from the server prior to the analysis function.

This is more of a problem with the second package because the reference data are downloaded within the function that conducts the analysis.

Now that this is happening with more than one package (both of these scripts were working perfectly before yesterday), I'm thinking it is something systematic within R or R studio.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error. Tested with `R 4.2.0` and `gage_2.46.0`. Is there anything unusual about your computer network that might interfere with requests?

Comment: @MrFlick, I have tried this on two different computers and two networks - nothing has changed (as far as I can tell, at least) with my networks since these scripts were working last. However, after checking ```sessionInfo```, I am working with ```gage_2.44.0". I've now attempted to update ```gage``` to see if this is a versioning issue, but am getting a handful of warnings that the installer is unable to write to the directories that these dependencies should be installed within.

```

Comment: It would also be useful to check what version of `curl` is being used. I had `curl_4.3.2` listed in my `sessionInfo()`

Comment: I have ```curl_4.3.2``` listed as well. 

When updating to ```gage_2.44.0```, I am getting a handful of warnings for dependencies including gtools, Rccp, rland, icudt69l and stringi

Example error:

```
2: In file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\root\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\00LOCK\gtools\libs\x64\gtools.dll to C:\Users\root\Documents\R\win-library\4.1\gtools\libs\x64\gtools.dll: Permission denied```